# How to add more sources for Find Jar on Web in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

When I right-click a missing import, I have an option of "Find Jar on Web", but the Jars in the list are outdated.  For example, the newest ant jar on the list is [ant-1.7.1.jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1NkR.png), but I know that [ant-1.10.1.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ant/ant/1.10.1) is available from Maven Central.

How can I add more "sources" to the search of IntelliJ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the repositories is outdated in your IntelliJ, so, you can update with these steps, go to:

`Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Maven > Repositories`

Choose the `Remote` repository entry and click on `Update` button, this action takes some minutes, after of that, do the same with your `Local` repository, IntelliJ will be able to retrieve the last versions of your dependencies.

[image]

**UPDATE**

To view the remote repositories in IntelliJ, you can add in your `settings.xml` file ([check this](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/config-maven.html#ex-maven-nexus-simple)) or directly in your `pom.xml` file of your project.

This is the structure for your `settings.xml` file:

```
<project> 
  <repositories> 
        <repository>
            <id>maven-central</id> 
            <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url> 
         </repository> 
     </repositories> 
 </project>
```

And this is the structure for your `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependencies>
    ...
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>codehausSnapshots</id>
        <name>Codehaus Snapshots</name>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
        </snapshots>
        <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

After of add this configuration, IntelliJ will be able to detect the new repository.

*Notice: The updated specified in your pom.xml file (or inherited from parent project's pom and settings.xml)*

Comment: It says `No remote repositories` for that project, but in another project I see the URL that you posted.  How can I add a Maven repository?

Comment: In the current version of IntelliJ these settings are found at `File` > `Settings...` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Remote Jar Repositories`.